# I use my laptop (windows 7) for browsing only , can I run it in safemode always?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, safe-mode

> I use my win7 laptop (2GB) ,only for browsing .Can I always run it in safemode mode as if I open in normal mode my laptop becomes extremely slow may be due to scvhost , (not virus scanned using multiple anti virus) .So I always run it in safe mode where there is no problem.

But I have the following concerns about safe mode -

- Volume and brightness settings does not work in safe mode?
- Does my anti virus work in safe mode?I think it does not work maybe..
- Is it possible to get virus through net in safe mode?If yes , how to protect my laptop from virus in safe mode ?Is there any method/

Comment: Why not try to find out why it's slow and fix the actual issue? That is probably a better way to handle this.

Comment: @Seth i can't if i open in normal mode system become yes slow , I can't even the task which are running , it takes 10 min to open that.

Comment: Did you give it time? Otherwise it sounds like you might just have to reinstall if something is that severely broken. Beware that scvhost for Windows 7 has a bug that causes a memory leak/high CPU usage if windows updates is running. Do you have all current windows updates installed?

Comment: Can you: Sure;  Should you: No;  *Just fix the reason your computer is slow.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe Mode is a troubleshooting mode designed to start Windows with minimal drivers and running processes to diagnose problems with your computer.

You can find workaround to enable sound by google (http://www.ehow.com/how_7248126_turn-sound-driver-safe-mode.html), brightness control is not available since related driver is not loaded. Lots of Avti-virus can do scan job in safe mode, but i think little of them are designed to run in safe mode for real time protection.

So it is not suggested to always runing in safe mode. If you want to load less drivers and start little services for better performance, you can consider to boot to clean boot mode: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135, of course, do not disable the anti-virus services.